# What is the site language policy concerning differences between British and American English?

Tags: discussion, best-practice

So one of my posts recieved an excellent clarifying edit today. However, when I just came back to read it I noticed a change I had not seen before evangelisation had been changed to evangelization.

Obvious this conveys no change in meaning. So I assume it was considered a spelling mistake. Should I be trying to use US English when posting on this site? I will inevitably slip up by/on accident but I can try if it is highly preferred.

Comment: For what it's worth, [*-ize* is acceptable in British usage](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/4896/898). In fact, I've been trying to switch to it, but *-ise* is now ingrained. (And I can't find an en-GB-oed spellchecker.)

Comment: @TRiG You can always manually edit your spell checkers as the words come up.

Comment: @fredsbend: On every device? Yuck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The policy for British vs. American English across the entire SE network, as far as I'm aware, is that we ought to honor the spelling (and grammar) of the OP.

IOW, if you wrote in British English, it is an *incorrect* correction to change your spelling to conform to American English.  And vice-versa.

However, we must be gentile... many people aren't aware of the differences, and might think that "evangelisation" (not to mention other differences) is actually a typo.

My suggestion: Roll-back the change, or if it was part of a larger change, simply re-edit the post to revert to your preferred/original spelling/grammar.

If you feel it's a chronic problem, you might mention it in a comment to whomever edited your post, so they know they're making a mistake (probably quite honestly).

I don't think anyone here is on a crusade to convert SE to American (or British) English... I'm sure it's an honest attempt to improve things without realizing it can be controversial.

Comment: Thanks, it was only an infomation request: I'm not feeling oppressed or anything. I appreciate that US English is more widely spoken so thought I should ask if it was better to try to use it or if muddling through without it is also fine.

I'm sure I have unintentionally edited posts in a British English direction. If it isn't a big deal, it isn't a big deal. I just wanted to know what was considered best practice.

Comment: It was me. It was an afterthought of a larger edit (as quick as a right click and select). Now I know to stick to the OP's usage.